# Populate multiple items returned from Poswershell command in to variable

Tags: powershell, azure

I am trying to put together a script that will take an Azure Powershell command out put and populate the output into variable so I can run the next part of script. In this case it gets azure vm's not set to hybrid license model

Here is my get command, this outputs what I would expect in two columns:

```
$output = Get-AzureRmVM | where-object {$_.LicenseType -NE "Windows_Server" -and $_.StorageProfile.osDisk.OsType -eq "Windows"} | select Name,ResourceGroupName
```

Next, I want to take the vm and resourcegroup name it outputs and somehow and run them with these commands, this part sets the vm to use hybrid license model.

```
$rgname = "$output.resourcegroupName"
$vm = Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroup $rgname -Name "$output.Name"
$vm.LicenseType = "Windows_Server"
Update-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $rgname -VM $vm
```

My problem is I am having trouble linking these two together since the first `get-azurermvm` command can output several to hundreds of `VM's`.

If anyone could point me in the right direction of how I might get something like this working it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
$output = Get-AzureRmVM | where-object {$_.LicenseType -NE "Windows_Server" -and $_.StorageProfile.osDisk.OsType -eq "Windows"} | select Name,ResourceGroupName

$VMName = @()
foreach($item in $output)
{
    $vm = Get-AzureRmVM -Name $item.Name -ResourceGroup $item.ResourceGroupName
    $vm.LicenseType = "Windows_Server"
    $VMName += $item.Name
    Update-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $item.ResourceGroupName -VM $vm
}
```

Avoid the `double quotes("")` while assigning values of `$output`. Or you can directly use `$Output.Name` and `$Output.ResourceGroupName` instead of having a separate variable. Using double quotes will lead to each alphabet of the VM to be an array, which is not desired. If your first command has multiple outputs, then you can use a `foreach` loop and run the same command for an array of inputs. The `foreach` loop will take an array containing multiple values and process them one by one. As a result, your command `$vm = Get-AzureRmVM -Name $item.Name -ResourceGroup $item.ResourceGroupName` and `Update-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $item.ResourceGroupName -VM $vm` will run for each an every element of `$Output`.

I am defining an additional array named `$VMName` in case, you need the names of all the `VM's`, for further use, but IMHO, that is redundant as you can directly get it from `$Output.Name`. Moreover, I can't possibly fathom the use of `$vm.LicenseType = "Windows_Server"` line, unless you will be using it afterwards.

Comment: thanks, I think this is getting me closer. It looks like it works for teh $rgname with $items, but there is another column I need to populate at the end of the $vm= line.  Do I need another foreach line?

Comment: Also edited second snippet above, $rgname would be $output.resourcegroupname and the vm name should be $output .name

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then are you implying that you want the names`(precisely $Output.Name)` of all the `VM's` against which you have run the `Update-AzureRmVM` cmdlet?

Comment: yes, $output.name and $output.resourcegorupname will provides several rows of results, those need to be put in the that second $vm= line.

Comment: Where is `$vm=line`? I don't see that anywhere in your code!

Comment: $vm = Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroup $rgname -Name "$output.Name" will need the multiple values as well as the last line Update-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $rgname -VM $vm since it has $rgname in it

Comment: That is what a `foreach` loop do. It will take an array containing multiple values, and process them one by one. Have a look at the solution now!

Comment: That last edit did it! Thanks Vivek. works great and shows me how to use the foreach loop properly now. To your question, the $vm.LicenseType line updates the azure licensing model to hybrid licensing model for azure vm's, it changes it from "None" to Windows_Server, thanks again! I voted as answered but did not let me choose it, as I am too new I guess.

Comment: @olirm: Glad that it worked. And yes you are right with the use of `LicenseType`!